# Hbase Atomic read and delete a row

Tags: java, hbase, apache-zookeeper, mutual-exclusion

We are using a hbase table as a big queue. Many clients can insert into it, and many clients want to read data from it. Problem is mutual exclusion. At span that a client read data until delete it another client can read it too! But we want to make sure each row return to one and only one client.

I should mention we are using Java hbase client.

Is there a way like get and delete a row atomically or get and update in hbase, or some thing that could manage this situation?

I found RowLock mechanism but it's deprecated and does not exists anymore. Also there is a distribution lock using zookeeper but it does not seem efficient.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that approach

1. get required row. Check in java code that it is not used by one one (specific column==0).
2. check the row exists and not used by anyone. If yes, then mark it(ie. increment column value from 0 to 1) x. All that can be done by checkAndPut
3. delete row using checkAndDelete.

Comment: Simple and excellent idea. but I just removed second step, but if I could successfully delete a row, I suppose row is mine and I return it, but if I can't delete it It means another client has already removed it (and owns it)  and I'll query for next row.

Comment: sounds reasonable. Just one point: if you delete a row and than something happens with thread that process it, you will lose the data.

Comment: For some other reasons I have a backup table, if client says i'm done with data then I remove row from backup table too, otherwise I restore data from backup table.